# Vega-Lite multiple layer chart with selection

Tags: vega-lite

I am trying to recreate a report that was done in [Tableau](https://public.tableau.com/app/profile/kcmillersean/viz/ContextualDetail/WOW20222Week6LetsaddContext), using Vega-Lite. I'm not entirely sure if it is possible to do it. I'm struggling with the bar charts based upon the selection made in the scatterplot. The bar chart should be created as follows:

1. Selected item
2. All entries in the reference box (*light blue area*) - (excl. the selected item)
3. All other entries outside the reference box (excl. the selected item)

If it is possible to create a similar chart/interaction in Vega-Lite, can someone please guide me towards a solution. Attached my attempt to recreate ( [Open in Vega Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-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-AA5OAAQAAgACSQBA8BgGgQXg1AKlbUD5y7ai32zGtLCw3DVzgAAPC9TXlC0qg7dUuwzejT0w7CcIATSGLJyI8W5fDmZCIm8QSTw-cMMKGegcL6Gwjk3ONm2TMowmozsgzolT0LUjSYBw74kCyNh-1vNBZ0fGjFJTJcq0s7oAHkSK4+Mqm8MR7lMxTXwsld0F8kEyDkciNktA9+KeMJKS898fMsAAFQc8jHQRtBGfSplKIk92Qsy0OikAACUTWUOAcINCB-ijcjvHLPwFJfGqoPQABlNgGE0uyHKcnc0EiGT-UPeF+sY9AABV8v0CA4G3bjUA8MIyjKOdwqiDKhNU7pVrYpAvW2jZfQWKr1k807svQAA1UjaBK8iKj2jwMvm8tFr7AB1K6SNkMhMAS5ySitMpGhStNnmUyClpAYH9EwHD3psT6cRhvdbl6yInqigb0bHNgEE3MhEqMkz+MFCDvNqqx-iYQjSt3LkxFKXrzMsSJhPDQ4fzgKAVigUbEs1Xw+KRwGRXQIWzssAAZEbPRjLmXJuf7GeR7UVZer9gUK3JlE6v69v5o3he6dcIFcWAGA27BrvjQkml6pS7dV9Bzydz0IBoHAcBoRL0oqRHn27JWQGN2rA5kBg7E6rqwk8gH7XjxPyawpggggHJvsaIkfZO6k87RrDtDZAnKjj9znj9k3mJwgApOAbA2icYa8OZ5djyvBftyxfKyf4TWQRKVV8BmFdJ0f-ZAYbRps7TdLgmG5etMCu0XN9q77ABVdQYESvdvDcgGBeVse3u7hAYPI7km4Bpf75X4HPSgOQQ5vFNHaNwSY+2ZgnZIABdFIIBMBBDyIMGwCAjCgCgDoKW-xwyqGHAgSgmYcIAF4CE4UiDhAA-DhbBmJKA1hwqgHCAByXy9Bu44QABQIDgNGXIABKBhuIrqWC3ACAA+oxJIkClAwD-rINBmAUEqH0FAOwOBSTyHQKcZQOFoBqHMDYHCOBjhYyhjhFhOFiA0FEmwv+ghIg8NxACGgyh6CeDEI+f4Y5u4KKatAFRajLCaNMfAHCmZu6DigM1JgbA2LsI8d3OxuJkA2CkpoWBY4cDdBBBLBxTiXE7TcTA8JbBowQzQKACcqSkBkDIHFT8ABHIWShYiWMEJbdA84YFjm8GUkAVSal8HDHUjwuJml-DaWBGBbEel9NqYMxpIBRmtMsNxSZ3TKnVNmd0IZIyWnjJWUoGxQwenaF0N0AAxMobwcAKibWSEkD4PjlGh38Ro5QWicAeiHBAHCiDtFyL0YYxysSkCeJsN4exSgcDAkIsUYwIBYycOWX8cW8iXDIuyakzA6TugfM3KihZuzYVQWgUoE5egFE11El3HucAJwSI+Ai7oJEyAwGECy-FG1JgYtAFijJlhcVDlxAldAz9XbSlIDYHZYyiWMWgRIpQSSUk8uxfyz5+LmmuksBcjwygdXDKUFDI4KwcBoDgXoQpsjik0x6VM1Jiy9n4gNSq9AdSGC5BWGYGgpABEcWKKARByB5HoDAAoeIBqLxZEOAwQV0xw2jmKLEHQG17lKAqf63Zlh5xOr5S6t1Q46DBG9UoJAvqekBrUJYBQABSXEkssgJqTXAJQ7M-g5U0da6YYQYE6MmD0s4yBNxGCeM0CIjQSWwLoL29AOUdLNKxnVWEMCNWCB6TI6MLzQBQqCMg9AnKUW4jJecxUjRvhiDKDsEAh6tU9C5Dem9F6Q72AyKguQ672DqM3dCnd4x0X4sQKoipibBAbVJToclLYwhdtA6chCUG9g6SyM+kAa66Dvp6VuwilhmWsqvFgXE-6sVoCAyBy9YHuhMH+KOC9V70BnOPae899yHlKL8Wh15Wi3TNV+WYgMOFOHcNkMC0FHgIUgEVT03lmSGC9pcHAtgiGf7OIvuSVUpgENwDshAZThhiRiEkcho4RzaNIDCCZkzF6iklNpqktNvSNkDO6PxmMUqlntNhMW0tdqhiBsrTWuNkaRoxq5DAyTlhXXuoLSsIt4w0FTtAP2jc6jDDDoUKOuVSg2JrPi2oTEoRdpMd2I81jwrelvJwpxn5QwgnNXlHxrhMYhPd0aKJ8TmLnVLGk1tOTCncnKYiKp7rGmwZGF0-pw5krjOmamxZy1VmbXTPsxQcMTncguYdeabNWy80esLduD1U7V74gK-Fljzy2OlY45uZqJizFhAMWqxrNgxAteBEqtJOaOsyfg-JuAim8mKVk+pzT2nohjoOYZibIALmNGUDDxoM2-5zZs32nLO6u33JJSd3xZ2SuBLMbVjm+jYDAixtYo44LcRxIm3CorOP1EXZwoTnCxObBY1+bVthVOEkGvgRAANRh9OteVR9wnCOrWlOR3ajN6BhFiP2OGzAU7ZDScEC4DSPS2AmpFfV1bTTpdTSUEMJqkPHmDjmymkAtrQAzIc5YFbgD7XLMde9rbEXPXRf290QaR3wcslXa+1Dwq4UYe-Xu7J0HwNQ+PcoM9UC9djMzW8Y7ijseqPO4E2r9vTFsGZzAEnj2KcKtexJ9rNhOvskG39vrlABtA+G6gQwAQPBjYh1qrkTB2ztjF0j0AVu7P9KW45nXDv9fcU22F7bkWvV7cnV7o7GPmOp5eQzsxOBZ10BCbURnwJc-57J4IETlOQVeIb1jp5afcdlaZyztnVW19sDnZv0kj3udieL21kXwJu8dvKWW-XsvGIPNPQ0BldXQ1dWcNctcxNh81tM13MQAjcT8U8IkoxrULc+8bdB87cYD49XMwIgC-UFlvMK10Bq0L1Pdcp1951F1fcjMX1UCN0QAQ8kUuV8UaMo8eQY9GNcDxklxm1yAzcQCVcXBYskMEtB0G8SxIh9N4EyAMhDAocoAuQlClDcQLkrkbkLA5UU0z9it6dAks9fkZ0H8N8F1n9Odj8wUXtkkS8Psy8vs1Mfsq84Ra8ftgcjAm8W8-daN29O94cLVEcf9LcFsB9Px7dYC3N1Rx9c03dds7l6VoEgA) )

Any assistance or guidance is appreciated. Thanks